# hover is not working with jQuery 1.9

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
HTML:

<div id="test">
    <p id="hello">HELLO</p>
    <p id="no-hello">NO HELLO</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
 $('#test').click(function() {
       alert($('#hello').is(':hover'));
        if ($('#hello').is(':hover')) {
            alert('hello');
        }
    });
```

I had been using jQuery 1.6 and it worked fine. But now for some reason 1.9 was used instead and this has stopped working.
I tried finding solutions on the net but did not get any hint about this.

Thanx All.

Comment: please have a look now

Comment: "jQuery only supports selectors that actually select DOM elements - everything else is ignored." [From these old docs](http://docs.jquery.com/API/1.1.2/DOM/Traversing/Selectors). In newer documentation, it's not even mentioned.

Comment: Have a look at your console—it will save you a whole lot of time:
`Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover`

Answer (score 0):

If you need the id of clicked area in this context, you can try:

```
$('#test').click(function(event) {
   alert(event.target.id);
    if (event.target.id == "hello") {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/HynAU/)

But the method you provided is not supported on jQuery 1.9+

See one alternative for your method:

```
$('#test').click(function() {
   alert($('#hello:hover').length ==1);
    if ($('#hello:hover').length) {
        alert('hello');
    }
});
```

[Sample 2](http://jsfiddle.net/HynAU/1/)

Answer (score 0):

As A.V. pointed out, your method will not work in jQuery 1.9+.

However why are you doing this in such a way?

Why don't you simply assign two different click events to `hello` and `no-hello`?

```
function doOnBoth() { ... };

$("#hello").click(function () {
    doOnBoth();
    alert('hello');
});

$("#no-hello").click(function () {
    doOnBoth();
    alert("not hello");
});
```

Or you can assign classes to both elements, then a click event to that class and separate click events for the IDs.

The problem is, **it is possible to trigger click without triggering hover first**.

Unless I don't get what you want to achieve...